# Apigility not save documentation fields

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2, composer-php, laminas-api-tools

I have a problem with Apigility.

When I will save the documentation of my REST service, only the field that describe the entire  REST service is saved.

I am trying save the response body, for instance, without success.

Some  things that I have checked before posting:

- I have the opcache and apc disabled.
- All requests after press save button are 200 OK.
- I try run composer update, without success.

My composer.json

`json
{
    "name": "zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Apigility",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "api",
        "apigility",
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://apigility.org/",
    "support": {
        "email": "apigility-users@zend.com",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/apigility",
        "source": "https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton",
        "issues": "https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton/issues"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 5000
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev",
            "dev-develop": "1.1-dev"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.8",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.3",
         "zfcampus/zf-apigility": "~1.0-dev",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-documentation": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*",
        "hounddog/doctrine-data-fixture-module": "0.0.*",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
        "zfr/zfr-cors": "1.*",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-documentation-swagger": "1.0.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-welcome": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-deploy": "~1.0"
    }
}`

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace or any error in Developer Tools of your browser in the requests or network tab bit? I had an issue the other day with file permissions and apigility which meant the ajax call was returning a 404 and not saving my config or docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug on Apigility.

See https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin/issues/226.

My workaround for now is force the $controllerType on file ./vendor/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin/src/Controller/DocumentationController.php to 'rpc'.

Comment: The bug is in zf-apigility-admin v1.0.4. It has been fixed in dev

Answer (score 1):

The update to dev-master worked for me:

```
"zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin": "dev-master"
```